# Is there any way to cancel IBM worklight request in IOS

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I send a request using IBM worklight API now I want to cancel that ongoing request but I checked there is not API to cancel the ongoing request, Is there any way to cancel the worklight request

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "no".

There is no way to cancel an adapter request once it has been sent.

Perhaps you should explai the scenario. With proper logic you could maybe not send the request to begin with.